# Create Asp.net MVC Application (not core) with visual studio code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code, kali-linux

I have a question and I searched it on the web and I can't find any answer.

How can I create a ASP.NET MVC web application sample in VS Code?

**Note**: I don't want to create a .NET Core application

And second question is: how can publish the ASP.NET MVC web application in VS Code?

**Note**: I using Kali Linux

Comment: You should add "mono" to your search queries... I'd be somewhat surprised if you find much benefit of using VSCode so... may be interesting self-answered questions so.

Comment: What's "mono" ?

Comment: Thank's for your answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No VS Code does not support ASP.NET Web Application. Refer https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp

> Due to this focus, many standard C# project types are not recognized by VS Code. An example of a non-supported project type is an ASP.NET MVC Application (though ASP.NET Core is supported).

ASP.NET MVC Web Application will not run on any version of Linux as it has a hard dependency on the Windows OS (You could try Mono). .NET Core Web Applications can be run on Linux.